# Trouble displaying screen in MouseListener method

Tags: java

I am coding a game in Java. The first screen is the begin screen. On a mouse click, the screen is supposed to switch to a screen that lets you choose a character. Then, the next screen is the first game question. The character choosing screen isn't coming. It is just going to the first question. drawq is the boolean that determines if the question has been drawn. I had initialized it to false in the beginning of my code. Here is my mouselistener method, please help me find a way to get the screen that displays "Choose your character" and the image of the girl.

```
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //background image
                g.drawImage(theme.getImage(),0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT,null);
                //Choosing character screen
                g.drawString("Choose your character", WIDTH-1550, HEIGHT/6);
                g.drawImage(girl.getImage(),WIDTH-1550,HEIGHT/2,237,338,null);
                //switching drawq to false
                drawq=true;
                //draw next question on mouse click
                if(drawq==true) {
                     questions[whichquestion].draw(g);
                     drawq=false;
                     repaint();
                }
```

Comment: How are you implementing these "screens"? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Note: don't try to draw things in the middle of an event handler. All drawing should only go in the `paintComponent()` method. Any attempts to use `g` outside that method won't work.

Comment: I also suggest that use use Swing widgets like `JLabel` instead of drawing a string yourself. Do some more reading for a Swing tutorial to understand how to use these components as well as layout managers to create your UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have got the order of your code mixed up, you set drawq to true and then immediately afterwards check if it's true, which will obviously always result in the if clause beeing run.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you go back to the drawing board. You should create a `JFrame` subclass that has a `JLabel` and a `JImage` on it. Then when the user clicks the button, just show that `JFrame`.

In gneeral, don't use a `Graphics` object outside of `paintComponent()`. And don't use `drawImage()` or `drawText()` unless you have a good reason. In this case, a `JLabel` and a `JImage` are much more appropriate for implementing the elements in the screen.

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of tutorials for developing games on Java. Also here on SO there are many questions and answers. Just take a look at one or the other and let yourself be inspired.

An example of mouse input and screen output:

```
public class Main extends JPanel{
    private int clicks = 0;
    private Random rnd = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        var frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(new Main());
        frame.pack();        
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public Main(){
        addMouseListener(new MouseInputAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
                clicks = e.getClickCount();
                repaint();
            }
        });
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawString("Click your Mousebutton! One, two, three times or more ;-)", 20, 20);
        if(clicks > 0) {
            g.drawString("Clicks counted: " + clicks, 20, 40);
            for(int i = 0; i < clicks; i++){
                g.setColor(new Color(rnd.nextInt(256),rnd.nextInt(256),rnd.nextInt(256),255));
                g.drawLine(20, 60 + i * 10, 100 + i * 20, 60 + i * 10);
            }

        }
    }
}
```